# Lower and Upper limited exponential growth

Tags: matlab

I'm currently evaluating the performance of several modulations in 5G NR for various SNR values. In this situation, it's more important to acquire data from the -17 to -5 SNR interval.

And as such, I'm trying to generate a exponentially incremented SNR vector from -17 to 11, but I am unable to think of any 'proper' solution to this problem.

[Example pretended growth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wylvF.png)

Its mostly a mathematical problem, sorry if it's not a proper question for stack overflow.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to generate a an exponential sequence within a range. The value num_values specifies the number of values within the sequence. The sequence is initially generated with a range >= 1 and then afterwards scaled to the negative range as the log of a negative value is complex.

```
num_values = 100;
min_value = -17;
max_value = 11;
value_range = max_value - min_value;

sequence = exp(linspace(log(1),log(value_range+1),100)) + (min_value - 1);
```

This generates:

[image: Figure of exponential sequence]